# How To Make A Buttons Appear Progressively In tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have made a small application with tkinter and Python 3 which has four buttons on the top of the window to form a menu.  It works fine but I want to know how to make the buttons appear along the window over a period of time starting from a single button in the center when first started rather than being statically placed in the center.

Here is my script so far:

```
import tkinter as tk

class utilities(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.window()

    def window(self):

        self.pluginrun = tk.Button(self)
        self.pluginrun["text"] = "Run Existing Plugin"
        self.pluginrun["command"] = self.run_plugin
        self.pluginrun.pack(side="left")

        self.owning = tk.Button(self)
        self.owning["text"] = "Add A New Plugin"
        self.owning["command"] = self.plugin
        self.owning.pack(side="left")

        self.webpage = tk.Button(self)
        self.webpage["text"] = "Webpage"
        self.webpage["command"] = self.web
        self.webpage.pack(side="left")

        self.more_info = tk.Button(self)
        self.more_info["text"] = "More"
        self.more_info["command"] = self.more
        self.more_info.pack(side="left")

    def run_plugin(self):
        print('Running Plugin')

    def plugin(self):
        print('Available Extensions')

    def web(self):
        print("Opening Webpage To Python.org")

    def more(self):
        print('Made Entirely In Python')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
show = utilities(master=root)
show.mainloop()
```

Which gives this result:

[image]

When first opened I would like it to look like this:

[image]

and over a period of time for more buttons to appear alongside one at a time until it looks like the first image.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please show a sample of your code, the output you would like to see, and your current output

Comment: Please post code samples to show what you mean.  This question cannot be answered as it stands because it doesn't contain anything actionable.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create a button that then shows more buttons next to it. This is simple enough but you need to show what you have tried so far as stack overflow is not here to write the code for you but help you thorough codding problems you run into while you build you application. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all your buttons to a list and then use a repeating timed method to pack each button in the list one at a time at a set interval.

I created a counter that we can use to keep track of what button is going to be packed next from the list.

I also created a new list to store all the buttons in.

Then I modified your `window()` method to add each button to the list instead.

The last thing was to create a timed method that would use the `self.counter` attribute I created to keep track of what button is to be packed next.

In tkinter the best method to use to keep a timed loop or set a timer for anything is to use `after()`. Using `sleep()` or `wait()` in tkinter will only cause the entire tkinter app to freeze.

Take a look at the below code.

```
import tkinter as tk

class utilities(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.list_of_buttons = []
        self.counter = 0
        self.window()


    def window(self):

        for count in range(4):
            self.list_of_buttons.append(tk.Button(self))

        pluginrun = self.list_of_buttons[0]
        pluginrun["text"] = "Run Existing Plugin"
        pluginrun["command"] = self.run_plugin

        owning = self.list_of_buttons[1]
        owning["text"] = "Add A New Plugin"
        owning["command"] = self.plugin


        webpage = self.list_of_buttons[2]
        webpage["text"] = "Webpage"
        webpage["command"] = self.web

        more_info = self.list_of_buttons[3]
        more_info["text"] = "More"
        more_info["command"] = self.more

        self.timed_buttons()

    def timed_buttons(self):
        if self.counter != len(self.list_of_buttons):
            self.list_of_buttons[self.counter].pack(side ="left")
            self.counter +=1
            root.after(1500, self.timed_buttons)


    def run_plugin(self):
        print('Running Plugin')

    def plugin(self):
        print('Available Extensions')

    def web(self):
        print("Opening Webpage To Python.org")

    def more(self):
        print('Made Entirely In Python')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
show = utilities(master=root)
show.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a million.  I would never have thought of using a list. The answer is actually better than I had ever hoped for and am not surprised to hear that time.sleep() is not a good idea (as I been trying to do it with this for hours) and think this definitely deserves best answer. Thanks Again : )

Comment: @Simon: Glad to help. List are a very useful tool in python. You can also do this with dictionaries if you want to keep a name associated with the widgets you can use the name as the key and the widget definition as the value.

Comment: I know lists are very useful but as I said above I have never even thought of using them in Tkinter.  I will definitely keep this in mind in future.  Thanks again : ]

Answer (score -2):

Add the `Buttons` inside a `Frame`, which you centre, and then as you add more `Buttons`, the `Frame` should centre them. If not, you may need to call `root.update()`, to re-centre the `Frame`.

Comment: This helps but it does not explain how to make a delay happen before each button appears. Could I just use time.sleep()?

Comment: `root.after(ms, method, arg1, arg2...)`

Comment: This could be very useful  but I am not sure what argument to put in `method` At the moment I have this `root.after(1500, method?, self.pluginrun.pack(), self.owning.pack(), self.webpage.pack(), self.more_info.pack())` is this correct?

Comment: `root.after(1500, lambda: [self.pluginrun.pack(), self.owning.pack(), self.webpage.pack(), self.more_info.pack()])`

Comment: I've tried it and I still can't get it figured out the whole window keeps freezing.  I'll think I'll use the answer above (thanks for the answer though) I'll keep trying it out and see if I can get it to work.